# Send JSON to Django template

Tags: python, jquery, django, ajax

I have a very basic Django view that, once it receives a request, should send a response to the page that the user is visiting, so that i can display a message on that page, without having to refresh the page.

Here is my view:

```
def Action(request):
    response = ''
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if request.POST.get('ajaxform', False) == 'submit':
            data = request.POST.get('formdata', False)
            mymodel = Userdata()
            mymodel.save()
            response = 'Submitted!'

    return HttpResponse(json.dumps(response), content_type='application/json')
```

Basically, when a POST request is received, this view should send a JSON response to the template with the message `Submitted`.

This view works, when i'm browsing my template, on my Dev tools i can see the JSON response `Submitted` being received by the page, but i don't understand how can i show it using Jquery.

Can someone point me out on how could i create a Jquery function that is triggered only when a Json response is received by a Django view?

Basically, in this case, when the Django view fires the response `Submitted`, my Jquery function should receive that message and do some stuff with it.

I tried this:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "/mytemplate/Action",
  type: 'get',
  dataType: 'json',
  success: function (data) {
    console.log(data)
  }
});
```

The problem with this function, though, is that nothing is being printed in my console, although i can see the response on my Network tab.

Answer (score 1):

My guess would be that, since you are calling the json.dumps in a string, your jQuery is also receiving a string. Maybe try calling json.dumps({'response': 'Submitted!') in your view.

An easier solution may be to use the ".done" callback, which is triggered after the post request is successful. This way, you won't need a specific response from the python view. Doing this, a simple HttpResponse('true') should work.

More specifics about the .done callback here: https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/

**Edit after clarification**

The first problem is in your view. There, you specified

```
if request.method == 'POST':
```

but your ajax request is using the GET method

```
  type: 'get',
```

Besides that, you still sending a string response, and not an 'stringfied' dictionary.

I made an working example similar to your post. IMO, your view should be:

```
def Action(request):
    response = ''
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if request.POST.get('ajaxform', False) == 'submit':
            data = request.POST.get('formdata', False)
            mymodel = Userdata()
            mymodel.save()
            response = 'Submitted!'

    return JsonResponse({'resp': response})
```

For making the request and dealing with the response, I made a $.post, which is more concise

```
$.post("/mytemplate/Action", 
       params,
       function( data )
       {
           console.log(data )
       }
       )
```